# CSS fix dropdown menu not showing on monitor resolution

Tags: css, menu, resolution, monitor, dropdown

So I just found out the drop down menu on my new site is not working properly on different monitor resolutions. I was wondering if anyone know hows to fix the CSS on this.

I was able to test it on my laptop and my desktop on different display sizes, and the following resolutions are giving me problems: (not sure if there are more):
1600 x 900
1024 x 640
1280 x 720
1280 x 800
2048 x 1152

My site is http://livinghealthywithchocolate.com/ and the dropdown that's not working properly is under the RECIPES tab. When you hover over RECIPES the dropdown menu gets hidden.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set high `z-index` property to your list items